# Using Internet explorer driver downloaded through maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium

When I'm specifying the path of iedriverserver or any other browser driver, I have to set it using system property.

This is my code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","Driver path");
```

If i'm downloading the iedriver via maven, is there any way to find its path and put it in `system.setproperty()`?

Comment: How you have you download the server exe? What did you use in POM?

Comment: So do you mean your selenium is run as part of the build process, and you need to set the system property for it?

Comment: hi, I have specified to download the  iedriver server from maven repository. How to specify the path of that , to set the system property.? @adrian\

Answer (score 0):

When you are using POM no need to specify the path for jars....POM will do it for you automatically.

IF not using maven, Download the ieServer and pass it to driver path

use this

```
 String driverPath = "IE driver path";
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath+"IEDriverServer.exe");
Webdriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: hi, Jars I'm not adding manually. I just want to add the path of Iedriver in the system.set property.